# How to ``define-values'' in a for-clause?

Tags: racket

I'd like to `define-values` two integers to identifiers `p` and `q` inside a `for-clause` in a `for/fold`.  Can I do this?

```
(define (benchmark x0 ls)
  (let ([primes-generator (all-pairs-gen ls)])
    (for/fold 
        ([failures 0] [f_cost 0] [it_cost 0])
        ([(p q) (primes-generator)]
         [r (pollard (* p q) x0)])
      `((failures (+ failures (if (false? r) 0 (cadr (assq 'factor r)))))
        (it_cost (+ it_cost (cadr (assq 'it_cost r))))
        (f_cost (+ f_cost (cadr (assq 'f_cost r))))))))

(define (all-pairs-gen ls)
  (generator ()
   (for ([i (in-range (length ls))])
     (for ([j (in-range (add1 i) (length ls))])
       (yield (values (list-ref ls i) (list-ref ls j)))))))
```

I'm getting:

```
> (benchmark 2 (list 1 2 3))
result arity mismatch;
 expected number of values not received
  expected: 1
  received: 2
  values...:
   1
   2
```

EDIT2:

Tried

```
(define (test2)
  (let ([primes-generator (all-pairs-gen (list 1 2 4))])
    (for/fold ([acc 0])
        ([(p q) (in-producer primes-generator (void))])
      (* p q))))
```

and got:

```
> (test2)
in-producer: stop condition for multiple values must be a predicate, got: #<void>
```

Comment: Unless I’m misinterpreting, I think you just want `[(p q) (primes-generator)]`.

Comment: You mean like this?
`(define (test)
  (for/fold ([acc 0])
      ([(p q) (values 1 2)])
    1))`
This gives me arity mismatch.

Comment: If `primes-generator` is a multi-valued sequence, I mean you should be able to just write `(for/fold (....) ([(p q) primes-generator]) ....)`.

Comment: primes-generator is a function, so I need apply it: (primes-generator).  Otherwise I get `for: expected a sequence for (p q), got something else: #<procedure:generator>`.  (I've added `all-pairs-gen` to the question to see if it helps.)  See my new EDIT to see if you spot what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: I think you probably want `[(p q) (in-producer primes-generator (void))]`, in that case.

Comment: @AlexisKing Not sure I'm not using it properly --- see my EDIT2 in the question.  I got "in-producer: stop condition for multiple values must be a predicate, got: #<void>".